# Is there a way to force Google Maps to show names in English?

Tags: google-maps

Can Google Maps be forced to show some names in English, such as for the school names?

[image: Maps example in Korean(?)]

Comment: you mean some text or a link? how does it matter?

Comment: Do you mean English translations of Korean place names? I doubt Google maps has such a function. English tags in the maps are probably added separately.

Comment: so Google Map in this case is good for local people but what about for anybody in the rest of the world?

Comment: @pnuts some text that is a link and then what?

Comment: ok, I checked: there is no such link, on the desktop version of the google map website

Comment: Bing Maps does what you want. Place names are shown in your language not the local language that you are unlikely to be able to read.